# Getting error when using global variables

Tags: javascript

I use a global variables as follows:

```
var someArray = new Array();

for(i=1;i<=50;i++)

    someArray[i] = 0;
```

Then in a function, I use:

```
if(something == anotherThing)

    someArray[i] = 1; //works fine
```

In another function:

```
if(something == anotherThing)

{
    var i = 1;

    alert(someArray[1]); //returns fine;

    alert(someArray[i]); //returns undefined.

}
```

Can't figure out the error.

Even used:

```
window.someArray[x];
```

Comment: What do you expect `i` to be in the other function?

Comment: Also, use `[]` instead of `new Array()`

Comment: Based on your explanation, what you're saying seems impossible. Can you create a jsfiddle to illustrate?

Comment: What does `x` actually stand for? You seem to be using variables which don't exist. (And, is `i` deliberately global?)

Comment: I did -1 for an unclear question. None of the code snippets are showing the error. If you improve your question, I will remove my downvote.

Comment: Perhaps there's more code inside the last function? please post the whole function code where the alerts are being used.

Comment: The code is a bit long. Tried editing it, but of not of much use

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't broken. [Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gLRRQ/1/)

Note that the use of globals is evil. You should find some way to modularize your code. modul8/browserify, requireJS/AMD & closures/namespaces are popular ways to do just that.

Comment: @DᴀᴠᴇNᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ can't you use a normal font :(

Comment: Can't you use a real browser? ;) Can't edit name for a bit longer anyway.

Comment: @DᴀᴠᴇNᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ I mean stop using a font that's not the default font for all stackoverflow names

Comment: I understand; reasonable browsers should display it anyway. But no, I can't edit my name until 21 Dec.

Comment: @DᴀᴠᴇNᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ There's a hack to get around the 30 days limitation. You have to create a profile (with the same account and profile must also be linked) on an other Stack Exchange website and get the name you want on it. Then go on the tabs `Account` of that other profile, scroll to the bottom and click `Copy SomeOtherSESite profile to all StackExchange accounts`. It will copy both your information and name to your SO account.